# What exactly is Microsoft-WebDAV expecting in the response?

Tags: node.js, windows, webdav

I am working on something where the server needs to respond to a PROPFIND request from Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir

Essentially a filesystem request for `\\domain.example.org\api\endpoint\blah` goes out, and a nodejs server on my end records the request.

At the moment, it responds with an empty text reply, which of course results in errors on Windows' end, and more seriously, Windows will not attempt he connection again until some timeout period has ended.

The PROPFIND request itself always seems to have an empty body

What reply can I send back to indicate that a valid, but empty file exists at the endpoint?

Comment: Have you read the WebDAV spec? That would be a great place to start.

Comment: See my response below - a 404 response seems to satisfy the beast

Comment: It's not exactly a 404 response, you are saying that the specific properties the client asked for don't exist on the collection. The collection itself does exist.

Comment: How do I correct the request? Or should it work as it - the file does not need to function; I just need to avoid the server being cached as Non webdav

Comment: If it works it works, if it doesn't... then start reading the spec and implement just enough to pass. I spent about 10 years writing a WebDAV server. When in doubt, follow the spec. My project: https://sabre.io/

Comment: So then what exactly is happening when windows temporarily refuses to attempt the connection again? Still occasionally occurs - open the file handle, and the propfind request simply never occurs. Works again after several seconds

Comment: The only advice I can give is look at the requests the client is making, and return responses that are _correct_.

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct evidence it works, since Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir has no features for debugging

But sending a 404 response as follows appears to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:">
 <D:response>
   <D:href>/container/</D:href>
   <D:propstat>
     <D:prop>
     </D:prop>
     <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND</D:status>
   </D:propstat>
 </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

I also set Content-Type and Content-Length